# Share the url by email (catch automatic the url)

Tags: html, css, email, url, share

This is what i have right now.
I'm really bad at Javascript, so I have no idea of what to de here.

But i need a script or something, that automatically takes the url from the same page as the one you were on, when you clicked the button, and put it in the description of the email.

`<a href="mailto:?subject=Link til guide&amp;body=Du finder guiden her: http://www.website.com.">`

Answer (score 0):

Remove your "http://www.website.com" in the href, then place this at the bottom of your HTML but above the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*=mailto]'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
        els[i].href += window.location.href; // Adds current URL
    }
</script>
```

This will grab all anchor tags with "mailto", then add the current URL to the end of the href attribute.

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*=mailto]'), i;
for (i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
    els[i].href += window.location.href; // Adds current URL
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:?subject=Link til guide&amp;body=Du finder guiden her: ">test link</a>
```

Note: The code in the snippet adds the URL of the iframe, not the URL you see in the address bar. If you have this in an iframe, you will need more complex logic